# Rails: How to set the value of dropdown unordered list with data that is returned from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am using Haml and have a form on the page with several input boxes and dropdowns.  I am able to set the value of my input boxes like this:

```
%input#txtBillingAddress(placeholder="Address" value="#{@vendor["billing_address"]}")
```

I have this unordered list that is a dropdown:

```
#ddlVendorPosition.wrapper-dropdown 
   %span.selected Position
     %ul.dropdown
        %li Owner
        %li Manager
        %li Employee
```

Is there a similar way for me to set the value of this dropdown?  The params is:

```
@vendor["position"]
```

Thanks

EDIT: I want to set the value with the returned data so that the form can be edited, if necessary.

Comment: I don't use HAML, but if this is a form, can you implement the options_for_select helper instead? This is how I do this sort of thing in my forms. I can elaborate if you think this might be a solution for you. @david

Comment: @Benco - thanks for trying. If you want to put your solution in an answer, I will try to implement it and 'accept' if it works!  :)  I am not opposed to changing the format of the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have come up with:

```
#ddlVendorPosition.wrapper-dropdown
    - if @vendor["position"] != "None" 
        %span.selected #{@vendor["position"]}
    - else
        %span.selected Position
    %ul.dropdown
        %li Owner
        %li Manager
        %li Employee
```

If there is not a value (saved as "None", apparently), the "Position" placeholder will show.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So I guess it would be something like (again, I don't know Haml very well, but...):

```
= form_for(@vendor) do |f|
  = f.label 'Position:'
  = f.select :position,
      options_for_select([["Owner", "owner"], ["Manager", "manager"], ["Employee", "employee"]]), 
      prompt: 'Please select a position'
  = f.submit "Submit"
```

You can also do the same dynamically rather than hard-coding, but you might try this for starters.